# Editing data in a text file in python for a given condition

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
1 a 20
2 b 30
3 c 40
```

I need to check if the first character of a particular line is 2 and edit its final two characters to 12, and rewrite the data into the file. New file should look something like this:

```
1 a 20
2 b 12
3 c 40
```

Need help doing this in python 3.

Couldn't figure it out. Help.

Answer (score 0):

To modify contents of a file with python you will need to open the file in read mode to extract the contents of the file. You can then make changes on the extracted contents. To make your changes permanent, you have to write the contents back to the file.

The whole process looks something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Define path to your file
your_file = Path("your_file.txt")

# Read the data in your file
with your_file.open('r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Edit lines that start with a "2"
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if lines[i].startswith("2"):
        lines[i] = lines[i][:-3] + "12\n"

# Write data back to file
with your_file.open('w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Note that in order to change the last two characters of a string, you actually need to change the two characters before the last. This is because of the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character, which indicates that the line has ended and new characters should be put on the line below. The `\n` you see after `12` is the newline character. If you don't put this in your replacement string, what originally was the next string will be put directly behind your replacement.